# Android: Layout.addView() doesn't work

Tags: android, layout, view, emulation

When I try to run the following code I get an error. The emulator gives me this error message and then the app force closes:
*The application has stopped unexpectedly.* What is wrong?

```
import edu.chl.dat255.bluebanana.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProMan extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);

        TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        t.setText("Hello world");
        layout.addView(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full exception error please.  <i>The application has stopped unexpectedly</i> is a generic phrase used for pretty much all of them.

Comment: I don't know how to find any other error message other than the one that pops up. Nothing is written in the console.

"Sorry! The application Blue Banana (process edu.chl.dat255.bluebanana) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

Comment: More detailed error messages are available in the LogCat.  If you're in Eclipse, you can see it by clicking the "DDMS" button on the top right (may have to click the arrows first).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

In your xml file main xml layout android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set id for your root LinearLayout in main.xml like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
```

and then reference it as

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
```

instead of findViewById(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 0):

You should provide layout information on `TextView t . layout width and layout height should be provided. See code below.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.0F);
t.setLayoutParams(tvParams);

layout.addView(t);
```